# tensorflow windows create own plugin

Tags: windows, tensorflow

I have tensorflow+gpu successfully built on windows 10 with visual studio 2015, from the source code.

As a result, I get `tensorflow.dll` and `tensorflow.lib`.
I have `CUDA8.0` and `cudnn 5.0`; with a gtx 1080 gpu equipped.

However, my question is not about building and compiling tensorflow.
It's about creating tensorflow plugins.

I followed the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) to construct my own "plug-in".
and then I tried to compile a windows .dll; so windows would not export symbols automatically for me .
then I compile a static lib first and used your tools

```
/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/tools/create_def_file.py
```

to create a `.def` file for me and eventually used that to compile the `.dll`.

However, in my python code, when I tried to

```
correlation = tf.load_op_library(correlation.dll)
```

and I called

```
correlation.correlation()
```

with Correlation registered using `REGISTER_OP("Correlation")`;
It still tells me

> AttributeError: module '7b088d8b906b36d3e50721b0adbaaa6a' has no attribute 'correlation'

I think this is just a windows (or cl compiler) issue, maybe what REGISTER_OP("Correlation") did is just not picked up by the compiler,

so is there any thing I can do to make this happen on windows??

Comment: this is not a problem related to any particular errors. so if anyone just have worked out a way to produce tensorflow plugin on windows, please let me know.

Comment: I don't know, but perhaps the discussion in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1103 helps?

Answer (score 1):

Loading custom op libraries via tf.load_op_library() is not supported on Windows (at least with TensorFlow 1.8).
The workaround is to add your custom op into the TensorFlow library itself.
Follow the example of tf.user_ops.my_fact implemented in tensorflow\tensorflow\core\user_ops\fact.cc:

1. Put your C++ implementation in tensorflow\tensorflow\core\user_ops
2. Add python binding in tensorflow\tensorflow\python\user_ops
3. Compile TensorFlow (read  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake)
4. Replace tensorflow directory in your Conda environment with 
   tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_python\tensorflow
5. Your new op function will be imported in tf.user_ops

Comment: What do mean by not supported? Is it implemented or not?

Comment: It is not implemented for Windows.